# How can I put two "functions" in one angular ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I got this example:

```
 <button ng-click="vm.hideElement(dataItem.id ,'listView');active = !active;"><i ng-class="active ? 'icon-visibility_off' : 'icon-visibility'"></i></button>
```

It should call a function (`vm.hideElement()`) and set/toggle a css class attribute.
But it doesn't work. Only the `vm.hideElement()` function get called.

If I do this:

```
 <button ng-click="active = !active;"><i ng-class="active ? 'icon-visibility_off' : 'icon-visibility'"></i></button>
```

the class toggle work's fine.

If I do this:

```
 <button ng-click="vm.hideElement(dataItem.id ,'listView')"><i ng-class="active ? 'icon-visibility_off' : 'icon-visibility'"></i></button>
```

the function get called.

`hideElement` function code:

```
function hideElement(elementId, from) { 
    ElementsService.hideElement(elementId, from).then(function (success) { 
        activate(); 
    }, 
    function (error) { }); 
}
```

Comment: create a new function that does 2 (or more) things, and call her.

Comment: Please show function code as well.

Comment: the first one should work, but anyway I recommend adding another function to your controller, which wraps both those functions, and call that one

Comment: Try to make the function `vm.hideElement` `return true;` at the end.

Comment: Please post `vm.hideElement()` code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line to your vm.hideElement function:

```
$scope.active = !$scope.active;
```

This basicly does the same as putting `active = !active` in the ng-click.

The other option, should you use the vm.hideElement function in a situation where you don't want to change $scope.active, is to make a new function that sets `$scope.active` and calls vm.hideElement().